# File Upload to Local using Acr in Elixir

Tags: file-upload, elixir, plug

I am using Arc.Definition(https://github.com/stavro/arc) for uploading an image to the Local Storage.

My file_service.ex is below:

```
defmodule MyApp.FileService do
  use Arc.Definition
  use Arc.Ecto.Definition

  @image_types ~w(.jpg .jpeg .png .gif)
  @versions [:original]
  @default_filename "image.png"

  @heights %{
    medium: 400
  }

  @widths %{
    medium: 400
  }

  def __storage, do: Arc.Storage.Local

  def upload_image(%Plug.Upload{} = image, resource_type, resource_id) do
    store({%Plug.Upload{path: image.path, filename: @default_filename},
      %{resource_type: resource_type, resource_id: resource_id}})
  end

  def upload_base64_image(base64_image, resource_type, resource_id) do
    store({%{filename: @default_filename, binary: base64_image_to_binary(base64_image)}})
  end 

  def delete_file(image_url, resource) do
    delete({image_url, resource})
  end

  defp base64_image_to_binary("data:image/" <> rest) do
    rest
    |> String.replace("\n", "")
    |> String.split(",")
    |> Enum.at(1)
    |> Base.decode64!
  end
  defp base64_image_to_binary(base64_image) do
    base64_image
    |> String.replace("\n", "")
    |> Base.decode64!
  end
end
```

But, I am getting an error saying "no function clause matching in Arc.Actions.Store.store".

The stack trace is below:

> ** (FunctionClauseError) no function clause matching in Arc.Actions.Store.store/2
>           (arc) lib/arc/actions/store.ex:8: Arc.Actions.Store.store(MyApp.FileService, {%{binary: <<255, 216,
>   255, 225, 3, 48, 69, 120, 105, 102, 0, 0, 73, 73, 42, 0, 8, 0, 0, 0,
>   58, 0, 50, 1, 2, 0, 20, 0, 0, 0, 198, 2, 0, 0, 15, 1, 2, 0, 10, 0, 0,
>   0, 218, 2, 0, 0, 1, 1, ...>>, filename: "image.png"}})

Anyone, please help?

Comment: Can you post the whole stacktrace?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code

```
 def upload_base64_image(base64_image, resource_type, resource_id) do
    store({%{filename: @default_filename, binary: base64_image_to_binary(base64_image)}})
  end
```

's `store` is using wrong.

It only accept `tuple(file, scope)` or `filepath(map)`.

So it should be: `store(%{filename: @default_filename, binary: base64_image_to_binary(base64_image)})`.

See github's example:

```
# Store a file from a connection body
{:ok, data, _conn} = Plug.Conn.read_body(conn)
Avatar.store(%{filename: "file.png", binary: data})
```

---

I figure it out by reading traceback and arc's store implementaion:

```
  def store(definition, {file, scope}) when is_binary(file) or is_map(file) do
    put(definition, {Arc.File.new(file), scope})
  end

  def store(definition, filepath) when is_binary(filepath) or is_map(filepath) do
    store(definition, {filepath, nil})
  end
```

Comment: But, when I use the tuple(file, scope), or filepath(map) I am getting another error. 
(BadMapError) expected a map, got: "image.png"
        (elixir) lib/map.ex:423: Map.get("image.png", :id, nil)
        (absinthe) lib/absinthe/middleware/map_get.ex:9:

Comment: @TessyThomas That's another question of  `absinthe` instead of `Acr`. That means your question of this post is solved.